# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable AI PROGRAM TEST

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to write a program, that will try and find out what 5 numbers you entered like some AI thing. However, when I run my code I'm getting the following error:
`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Here is my code — what am I doing wrong?

```
__author__ = 'Vansh'
import random

def get_num_code():
    x1 = int(input("Enter 5 digit number code one by one:\n"))
    x2 = int(input(""))
    x3 = int(input(""))
    x4 = int(input(""))
    x5 = int(input(""))
    x = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]
    return x

def ai0(x):
    y = random.randrange(1, 10)
    if x[0] == y:
        print("digit 1 found: {}".format(str(x[0])))
        ai1(x)
    else:
        print("Digit 1 not found")
        ai0(x)

def ai1(x):
    y = random.randrange(-1, 10)
    if x[1] == y:
        print("digit 2 found: {}".format(str(x[1])))
        ai2(x)
    else:
        print("Digit 2 not found")
        ai1(x)

def ai2(x):
    y = random.randrange(-1, 10)
    if x[2] == y:
        print("digit 3 found: {}".format(str(x[2])))
        ai3(x)
    else:
        print("Digit 3 not found")
        ai2(x)

def ai3(x):
    y = random.randrange(-1, 10)
    if x[3] == y:
        print("digit 4 found: {}".format(str(x[3])))
        ai4(x)
    else:
        print("Digit 4 not found")
        ai3(x)

def ai4(x):
    y = random.randrange(-1, 10)
    if x[4] == y:
        print("digit 5 found: {}".format(str(x[4])))
        final(x)
    else:
        print("Digit 5 not found")
        ai3(4)

def final(x):
    print("5 digit code FOUND: {}".format(str(x)))

def ai():
    x = get_num_code()
    ai0(x)

ai()
```

Comment: Look closely at the error message -- it will tell you exactly what line the problem is on. Then you can narrow down the problem and do some debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a similar functionality with,

```
import random

x = input("Enter a number: ")
for i in range(len(x)):
   randomGuess = random.randrange(1,10)
   while randomGuess != int(x[i]):
      print('Digit',i,'not found')
      randomGuess = random.randrange(1,10)
   print('Digit',i,'found:',x[i])
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 123
Digit 0 not found
Digit 0 not found
Digit 0 found: 1
Digit 1 not found
Digit 1 not found
Digit 1 found: 2
Digit 2 found: 3
```

Comment: Giving someone an alternate implementation of their homework problem, without any description at all of what they did wrong or how they could avoid making the same mistake again? This seems the very epitome of handing out fish, vs teaching the skill.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought the code was self-explanatory. But I got your point.

Comment: This is, indeed, easy-to-read and easy-to-follow code; I don't question that it's self-explanatory for what it is. However, it isn't obvious how it answers the OP's question, other than by providing a homework answer that doesn't raise the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your ai4 function you are passing an int as a parameter, but it expects a list.

```
ai3(4)
```

should be a list - the other functions call it like

```
ai3(x)
```